# CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio 16 2019 in flutter

Tags: c, windows, flutter, dart, cmake

I want make windows app with flutter.so I installed Visual Studio 2019 with desktop development with c++.

when I use `flutter run -d windows` I see
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5dqN.png) error

I also installed latest version of CMake(version 3.20.0-rc4) and version of my Visual Studio is 16.0.0

Comment: Please don't post _images_ [and, especially, _not_ links to images]. You can do [the windows equivalent of]: `flutter run -d windows > logfile 2>&1` and _edit_ your question and copy-and-paste the contents of `logfile` [as text] in a code block here.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell from that image you aren't actually running cmake 3.20

Because Ninja Multi-Config isn't being listed as a generator. That flutter command you used isn't using the CMake you installed on your system. Or you need to restart your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem.

for resolve this problem I have 3 different way and I'm not sure which one resolve this problem.

**first uninstall CMake**

- if you run `flutter doctor` and don't see any error create another flutter project with `flutter create <project_name>` and run that with `flutter run -d windows`
- I was using Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 I update that to latest version(10.0.19041.0)
- I update my visual studio 2019 to latest version(16.9.1)